# How to get extra that is passed through several activities when using startActivityForResult() in parent activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I want to make a quiz app. the activities flow like this:
MainActivity -> ProfileActivity -> NewProfileActivity -> QuestionActivity -> ResultActivity -> Main Activity.

On ProfileActivity, it will show a list of names (using recyclerview). and it has a button that calls startActivityForResult(). On the NewProfileActivity, it has a button that will send string extra back to the ProfileActivity.

The problem is, I don't want the NewProfileActivity to go back to the ProfileActivity. How to pass the extra through several activities and then displayed on ProfileActivity?

In ProfileActivity

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, NewProfileActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PROFILE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

In onActivityResult() method

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == NEW_PROFILE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Profile profile = new Profile(intent.getStringExtra("profile_name"));
        mProfileViewModel.insert(profile);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.empty_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

In NewProfileActivity

```
final Button save_profile_button = findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    save_profile_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String profile_name = mProfileNameView.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewProfileActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("profile_name_extra", profile_name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

for simplicity, for the rest of the activities, I pass the extra by putting this code on the onCreate method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String profile_name = intent.getStringExtra("profile_name_extra");
```

and on the button, I put this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("profile_name_extra", profile_name);
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In the NewProfileActivity, user need to enter their name and that name will be displayed on the ProfileActivity. It works before, but it go back to the ProfileActivity when the button in NewProfileActivity is clicked. But I want it to go to QuestionActivity.

Comment: Which button are you pressing and what actions does that button take? Are you talking about the back button or some custom button that you have implemented?

Comment: the button in the NewProfileActivity. a custom button.

Comment: That button will always lead to the QuestionActivity. If you want to store data across activities as the commenter below has mentioned you can simply use shared preferences.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i will try using shared preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the data into the sharedPreferences object and then retrieve it back in any Activity you can. This way you can avoid the overhead of passing data to and fro between multiple activities. 
So in your NewProfileActivity save the extras into sharedPreferences and fetch it again wherever you want to. 
The documentation for writing and reading data from sharedPreferences can be found here

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. do I still need to use startActivityForResult() or just use startActivity() when I want to use the shared preferences?

Comment: You can use only startActivity() no need of calling startActivityForResult() now.